# Solving $\int \frac{x\ln x}{(1+x^2)^2}$

Tags: integration

Solving $$\int \frac{x\ln x}{(1+x^2)^2}$$

This should probably be done with substitution and partial integration. However I fail to find a good substitute. I tried $u = \ln x$ but that led me to an integral I couldn't solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u = lnx$, and $dv = \dfrac{xdx}{(1+ x^2)^2}$. So solve for $v$, and $v = -\dfrac{1}{2(1+x^2)}$. So: $\int udv = uv - \int vdu = -\dfrac{lnx}{2(1+x^2)} + \int \dfrac{dx}{2x(1 +x^2)}$, you can continue...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $t=1+x^2$, then integrate by parts, using $\bigg(\dfrac1t\bigg)'=-\dfrac1{t^2}$.